# How to nest require in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, namespaces, package

Suppose I have a namespace `parent.namespace`, which has two children `child1.namespace` and `child2.namespace`, i.e., both require `parent.namespace`. Both `child1.namespace` and `child2.namespace` require some package `(:require [some.package :refer [stuff]])`. Is there a way to require this package only once in the parent.namespace and then require only parent.namespace in both children without having to require `some.package` in each child separately?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no nesting or inheritance behavior like you are suggesting.  Each child namespace must look like so:

```
(ns child1.namespace
  (:require 
    [parent.namespace :as parent]
    [some.package :refer [stuff]))
```